# Logstash Elasticsearch output use parsed field from input file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a lot of old logfiles in the format `drupallogYYYYMMDD` that I want to throw in logstash and by default the elasticsearch output creates the index for today. I can overwrite that with `index: "...."` but is there a way to set this in the logstash conf file so it takes the `YYYYMMDD` from above and turn it into the naming convention `logstash-YYYY-MM-DD`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index option of the [elasticsearch output](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch) defaults to "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" but you can change it to "logstash-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}" if you prefer hyphens in your date.

The date that gets inserted into said index name pattern is the timestamp of each message (i.e. the @timestamp) field. Since @timestamp is UTC it might not correspond exactly to the date in your log filename depending on how you name the files and what timezone you're in. You should not attempt to change the timezone of the @timestamp field. Other tools depend on the mapping between a message's @timestamp field and the index in which it's stored.

Comment: yeah, since I got the timestamp field to be the actual syslog dates and not todays date the index is created correctly. Let's say I have a bunch of logfiles to run through in a directory. can I specify a `.../*.log` input file and logstash will eat through one after another?

Comment: Yes, wildcards are supported.